# How can I transform a table with only ONE cell into a simple value?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

For example: if I just have this table

```
---------
| power |
---------
| 100   |
---------
```

I just want the value 100 (a number in this case). And if for example, the value is a string I want to have the value of the string too.

I need this to incorporate this subquery into another query, more precisely in a condition function.

PS: I use M language (Power Query in POWER BI Desktop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you load the table in the query editor, you can right-click on the value `100` and select Drill Down. This will give you a single value instead of a table.

It does this using the M code `Source{0}[Power]` where `0` is the row index and `Power` is the column.

```
let
    Source = <data source for your table>,
    Power = Source{0}[Power]
in
    Power
```

There are other ways you can do this too. For example, the first element in the table's column:

```
List.First(Source[Power])
```

Comment: I found a way like this: Record.Field(Table.First(<powertable>),"power"). But you way is the simplest I think

Comment: Yep. There are a number of possibilities but I tried to give a couple of the simplest.